# Only one byte is read when reading just now opened SerialPort

Tags: c#, serial-port

Strange issue.

When I read from com-port with [`SerialPort.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549.aspx), then if data arrive, **only one byte is read on the first call**, disregards of `count` parameter and number of bytes available within timeout. All further readings are ok, only very first has problem

Using [`SerialPort.DiscardInBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.discardinbuffer.aspx) or close/open (reopen) com-port will **again** cause the problem of the first reading.

Here is some code:

```
var port = new SerialPort();
port.PortName = "com2";
port.BaudRate = 9600;
port.WriteTimeout = 1000;
port.ReadTimeout = 1000;
port.Open();

// ... send some data first

var read = new byte[10];
if (port.Read(read, 0, read.Length) != read.Length)
{
    // always here at first reading no matter what
}

// ... send some data again

if (port.Read(read, 0, read.Length) != read.Length)
{
    // not here anymore (unless error)
}
```

Issue doesn't appears if specified amount of data is already available to read when `Read()` is called.

---

Some explanation.

`Read()` is synchronous reading. It will return when specified amount of data is received or timeout is expired. As it seems, `TimeoutException` will be only thrown if zero bytes are received. If timeout is expired before requested amount of data is read, function will return number of bytes read. Thus, return value has to be compared to requested to see if reading was ok.

But very first call has a problem:

> If 0 bytes has arrived during timeout, then first call correctly waits for timeout and trigger TimeoutException. If at least 1 byte has arrived, then function immediately ends, ignoring timeout and requested number of bytes to read altogether.

This is how I see it. Am I wrong? What should I do?

---

Some more tests. Inserting `Thread.Sleep()` to ensure that when `Read()` is called, there will be all data available, will make problem to disappears.

Logically, let's add sleep for only first call. Yay. What???? The problem now appears with **second call** and **only second call**. In other word problem appears with the **first Read() what will not have all data available but only once**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because at the moment of reading, the other bytes didn't arrive, it will read only one byte because only one is there in the queue. So if at least one byte is there it won't wait for the required number of bytes since timeout has happened but it won't throw and exception. If none is there it will throw timeout exception. Therefore you should try reading until you read as many bytes as you need (10 in your case). You can try with something like this:

```
int count = 0;
var read = new byte[10];
while ((count += port.Read(read, count, read.Length - count)) != read.Length) ;
```

but what if timeout happens, maybe this can strengthen the code:

```
int count = 0;
var read = new byte[10];
while (count < read.Length)
{
    try
    {
        count += port.Read(read, count, read.Length - count);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException te)
    {
        //maybe increase ReadTimeout or something, use exponential backoff, your call
    }
}
```

Comment: There are solutions to overcome this problem. But there is still a problem with the very first call what will only read 1 byte, see question edit. Tell me please, why this only happens once with first call and **never** ever after? If I swallow first error somehow, then it will start working fine after that. Until com-port is reopened (or `DiscardInBuffer()` is called). Why? By design?

Comment: Ok, tests with longer packets shows that your idea seems to be right - always *combine* packet from peaces, because `Read()` can return **any number** of read bytes. This should have been mentioned on MSDN.

Comment: Btw, *if at least one byte is there it won't wait for the required number of bytes since timeout has happened but it won't throw and exception* - this is the point, timeout is not happening. It seems `Read()` will either wait until timeout is expired or **currently available bytes** are read. And then it returns. So if no bytes there it will just block until first byte is received and then return. Seems logical.

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry I didn't see your question earlier. That is the point, just let it read until you've read enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle this problem. If you are expecting a reply from a command you send you should sleep for at least 250 msec after calling the serialPort.Write() Before calling serilPort.Read(). Or if you know how many bytes your device is sending back to you can use the serialPort.BytesToRead property to delay reading until the number of bytes you expect are available.  If you are using the DataReceived Event you can set the serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold (default is 1) to prevent the event from being raised until the expected number of bytes are available. Keep in mind that the serialPort.Read method is not guaranteed to return the number of bytes requested.  That is why the serialPort.Read method returns an integer which is the actual number of bytes read.

Comment: If you don't know how many bytes you will receive from the device you can make a simple loop (with a delay in it) that queries the number of bytes available and keep looping until the result stops changing.

Comment: *"`serialPort.Read` method is not guaranteed to return the number of bytes requested"*, that's the core of the problem. I figured it out 1 year ago (see comments to accepted answer). Btw, `SerialPort` has some serious problem with its `DataReceived`, I will never ever use it again (only *hardcore* synchronous reading in separate thread).

Comment: Yes, SerialPort does have issues and serialPort.Read is not guaranteed to read the number of bytes requested as you said.  But I think it's important to point out that serialPort.Read does return as an integer the number of bytes that were read.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've found my solution I hpe this helps:

```
ireadCount = serialPort.Read(readBuffer, 0, serialPort.ReadBufferSize);
Thread.Sleep(1);//This can be removed, just use it in case need time to complete the reception.
ireadCount = serialPort.Read(readBuffer, 1, serialPort.ReadBufferSize-1);
ireadCount +=1;
```

This way I can have the whole response from the external device without losing the first byte.

Regards.-